# swift 3 Core Data : fetch data One to Many Relationship

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

let say i have 2 entity one category and other one is items and the relation is one to many (one category has many items), as of now i fetch all category fine, and i create other Items-tableview controller for selected category with segue that take the name of category to the new Items-tableview controller, so what i want is when i select the category it show only items belong to this category in the Items-tableview

in other one fetch data from items that belong to the selected category

any help

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Items from a Category just as you would any other attribute. You could pass this data in the segue.

Yes, a better solution might be to fetch items belonging to a category. Make an inverse to your Category->Item relationship. Then fetch items with a predicate to filter only items in a specific category.